# Viewing the response body for a failed mvn deploy-file command?

Tags: maven, deployment

I'm running a failing maven [`deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) (attempting to push a snapshot to a Sonatype repository). I see there's a `400` response, and with `-e` I can see a stacktrace. But I really need to see the response body to debug this issue.

Is there some way to get mvn to print out the response body?

Comment: And you can't look in the log files on the repository?

Comment: I don't run the repository.